# Failed to use ESAPI 2.1.0.1: AccessController class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultAccessController) CTOR threw exception

Tags: java, esapi

I am encounting a problem in using esapi-2.1.0.1.jar.

My develop environment:
Jdk 1.8
eclipse 2018-12

ESAPI works fine in method A, but fialed in method B.

```
package com;

import org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI;

public class MainEntryPoint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("A");
        System.out.println(ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML("<li>ABC some html here"));
        System.out.println("A end");
        
        System.out.println("B");
        System.out.println(ESAPI.accessController().toString());
        System.out.println("B end");
    }

}
```

console:

```
A
System property [org.owasp.esapi.opsteam] is not set
System property [org.owasp.esapi.devteam] is not set
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via file I/O.
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties as resource file via file I/O.
Found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory: C:\Users\Ansticelee\.esapi\2101\ESAPI.properties
Loaded 'ESAPI.properties' properties file
SecurityConfiguration for Validator.ConfigurationFile.MultiValued not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: false
Attempting to load validation.properties via file I/O.
Attempting to load validation.properties as resource file via file I/O.
Found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory: C:\Users\Ansticelee\.esapi\2101\validation.properties
Loaded 'validation.properties' properties file
&lt;li&gt;ABC some html here
A end
B
Exception in thread "main" org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException AccessController class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultAccessController) CTOR threw exception.
    at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:129)
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.accessController(ESAPI.java:85)
    at com.MainEntryPoint.main(MainEntryPoint.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:86)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/ConfigurationException
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultAccessController.<init>(DefaultAccessController.java:32)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultAccessController.getInstance(DefaultAccessController.java:22)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 9 more
```

What did I done? :

1. create a new Project in eclipse (Dynamic Web Project)
2. put "esapi-2.1.0.1.jar" & "log4j-1.2.12.jar" into folder WebContent/WEB-INF/lib
3. put "ESAPI.properties" & "validation.properties" into folder C:\Users\Ansticelee.esapi\2101
4. set VM arguments :
   `-Dorg.owasp.esapi.resources="C:\Users\Ansticelee\.esapi\2101"`
5. right click on MainEntryPoint.java > Run As > Java Application

   (remind :  MainEntryPoint.java is my java file)

(detail of 4.:
 in eclipse, right click on my project (Run As > Run Configurations... > Java Application > esapi2101 > Arguments > VM arguments)

detail of 2. & 3.
I downloaded esapi-2.1.0.1.jar from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/owasp/esapi/esapi/2.1.0.1/
I downloaded log4j-1.2.12.jar from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j/1.2.12
I downloaded 2 properties from https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/tree/2.1/configuration/.esapi

detail of method B:
I saw it in page.16 (step 5) from https://owasp.org/www-pdf-archive/JavaEE-ESAPI_2.0a_install.pdf

It is my first time of posting a question. 
Thanks for your patience of reading.
How could I make the method B mentioned above works fine?

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of this is Eclipse can't find the class

```
org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException
```

as evidenced by this **ClassNotFoundException**:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException
```

That means that you are missing whatever Apache Commons jar contains that class. (There are several Apache Commons libraries that ESAPI uses, so I can't be more specific without doing extra research and I'm in a hurry at the moment.) Given that you mentioned that you explicitly added the Log4J jar (in step 2 you mention 'put "esapi-2.1.0.1.jar" & "log4j-1.2.12.jar" into folder WebContent/WEB-INF/lib'), it appears that you don't have your Eclipse project configured as a Maven or Gradle project. Reconfigure your Eclipse project as a Maven or Gradle project and those transitive dependencies jars should get downloaded and pulled in for you automatically. If you don't take that approach, you are going to keep on running into similar problems.

One last important point... please use ESAPI 2.5.1.0, which is the latest version as of this posting. Because of the small size of the ESAPI team, we can only actively address issues that arise in the latest version at the time the question is posted. (In this case, I don't think your problem has anything to do with what version of ESAPI you are using, which is why I responded.)  Also if you plan to uses ESAPI for anything serious, you need to use a version that doesn't have any know vulnerabilities. Note that 2.1.0.1 has 2 known CVEs; see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.owasp.esapi/esapi for details and available versions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: well tank you sir for all what you guys have built, but the library setup is complicated and confusing. what about a setup guide includes the requirements to use the library?

Comment: I'm not sure how you have your Eclipse project configured, but if you set it up to be a Maven or Gradle project, all the jars should get pulled down from Maven Central and Eclipse should be able to find them automagically.

Comment: yes, you are correct, but I'm not using maven since I have custom jars with custom java framework. However, I found a pdf for version 2.* of the esapi and was helpful and clear. I'd recommend attaching the pdf somewhere on the website for the 2.5.(or latest)

Comment: the person who asked the question said, " I downloaded esapi-2.1.0.1.jar from". He clearly didn't know the library requires " commons-configuration.jar" at least to run without throwing any exception.  I'm saying this just to validate my point of attaching the guide somewhere. Again, thank you guys for this amazing library!

Comment: @MostafaOnaizan - Can you point me to the URL for this PDF of the ESAPI Guide that you found helpful? I can at least grab it and drop it into the 'documentation' folder for https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/. Thanks.

Comment: Also, while Matt and I try to be as helpful as possible, please understand that because we only have 3 regular active contributors and we all hold full-time jobs so we can't possibly support old versions, especially ones that are now over 7 years old. As a rule, we generally only promise to try to support the latest current version. We could do better if we had more help or someone to sponsor the project, but we have neither, so we do what we can.

Comment: Not sure this is the same Guide that @MostafaOnaizan was referring to or not (it's not a PDF, but may have the same content), but on our GitHub wiki page, there is this, related to using ESAPI with Eclipse: https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/wiki/Using-ESAPI-for-Java-with-Eclipse

Comment: this is the pdf I was referring to:
https://owasp.org/www-pdf-archive/JavaEE-ESAPI_2.0a_install.pdf

Comment: Ah. Thanks. That's outdated. Try https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/wiki/Using-ESAPI-for-Java-with-Eclipse instead.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone face this problem because you need the commons-configuration.jar along with the library. I recommend anyone want to use it search for the installation guide and see the requirements.
this is the guide for version 2.* say: `if you will be using the reference implementations provided with ESAPI,
there are additional dependencies you must provide in your project. (For
Maven users, the ESAPI pom.xml will include them automatically as
transitive dependencies).
Most jar dependencies can be found under the lib/required directory of
the ESAPI zip, and should be added to the classpath in the same manner
as above. URLs are provided for those not packed with ESAPI.

```
Configuration files (xml or .properties) can be found under the 
configuration/.esapi directory, and should be added to the .esapi 
configuration directory created above.
For DefaultAccessController: 
commons-configuration.jar: 
commons-lang.jar:
commons-collections.jar
ESAPI-AccessControlPolicy.xml
```

`

Comment: The jar that Mostafa refers to is a jar that you download from whatever release you are using from https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/releases. And for this jar, you should extract the contents and then put them in a directory where they can be found. See the class Javadoc for DefaultSecurityConfiguration at https://javadoc.io/static/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.5.1.0/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultSecurityConfiguration.html for details of how ESAPI.properties and other ESAPI configuration files are located.